# как сделать прокрутку текста виджета label из python kivy?

Tags: python, прокрутка, kivy, label

Я пытаюсь создать виджет текста (Label) из  python фреймворка kivy, но мне нужно, что бы текст прокручивался колёсиком мыши, когда заполнится. Скажите, как это сделать.

Answer (score 1):

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.factory import Factory


Builder.load_string('''
<Root@BoxLayout>:
    orientation: 'vertical'

    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: 1, 1, 1
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos

    ScrollView:
        size: self.size

        GridLayout:
            cols: 1
            padding: dp(5)
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.minimum_height

            Label:
                text: 'E ' * 6000
                size_hint_y: None
                valign: 'top'
                height: self.texture_size[1]
                text_size: self.width - dp(10), None
                color: 0, 0, 0, 1
'''
)


class Test(App):
    def build(self):
        return Factory.Root()


Test().run()
```

Но учтите, что максимальная длина текста в Label - 6800 символов.